# PHP class lifecycle with REST and PDO

Tags: php, rest, pdo

I've implemented a REST-based API (using Tonic, FWIW) so I have a central `dispatch.php` file that handles sending URI requests off to the appropriate classes. At the back end I have MySQL through PDO.

To implement my higher-level functionality I need to call about three or four REST APIs in a row, so I worry that all the construction and destruction of the PDO object and the connecting and disconnecting from the back-end database adds unnecessary overhead. I could store the PDO in the `$SESSION` array, I suppose, but that doesn't feel like the right way to go about things. What is the recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is really orthogonal to REST, and is a problem in just about every PHP application.

In any standard PHP application, the everything is created on the request, and destroyed at the end. This is the "share-nothing architecture".

That said, there is a project called [appserver-in-php](https://github.com/indeyets/appserver-in-php), which attempts to address this, by creating a server in PHP. If you use this, you can create you PDO object once, and have it available until you shut down the server, or a snake bites the ethernet cables.

Comment: +1 for the "shared nothing" comment, but I'd stay away from the php server.  If you're at the point where you're worrying about the performance overhead of PDO connections, you're probably beyond the point of using PHP as your HTTP server.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, and it's as I thought/feared. I just wanted to check I wasn't missing a trick.